# Standardize email label colors for all users accessing a shared inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, shared-mailbox

All of the users in our customer service department access a customer service inbox, and as they process the emails they add labels to them and move them to the corresponding sub folders. The issue they brought up is that user A labels them as green and see's them as green, user b sees those as white. Is there a way to make the label colors carry over?

Comment: How did you add this service mailbox to other users? As an additional Exchange mailbox or as a separate account? Also, what Outlook version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the categories in Outlook, it should sync with other clients as this property goes with mailbox other than client. You will also see the category in OWA when logging in with same this account.

You can check if it shows as expected in OWA, or check if User A or User B's client is connecting in Exchange mode or POP3/IMAP4. Exchange mode is recommended.

If my understanding to your issue is not correct, just help me clarify. :)